# number of NFAs given $a$ states

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. How many NFAs can there be with $a$ states and the input alphabet, $\Sigma = \{0, 1, . . . , b − 1\}$

Comment: Does your definition of NFA allow multiple initial states?

Comment: Yes multiple initial states are fine

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You’ll need factors to account for each of the following:

- the set of initial states;
- the set of acceptor states; and
- for each state, the set of transitions out of that state.

The first two are straightforward. For the third, notice that each of the $b+1$ possible transitions from a given state has $b+1$ possible targets: it can go to any state, or it can be omitted altogether. Why $b+1$ and not $b$? To account for $\epsilon$-transitions (or $\lambda$-transitions, if you use that notation for the empty word).

Comment: Sorry I got occupied. I think I might understand your hint. But to start I'm going to try this for a single initial state which shouldn't be much different than allowing multiple ones. For a single initial state, the set of initial states will be of size $1$. The accept states can be any of the $a$ states so I'm thinking the size of the set of accept states will be $a$. The transitions as you stated would be $b+1$. So would the number of NFAs in this case be something like $(b+1)^a$? I might be wrong about the total number.

Comment: @user27546: Any *subset* of the states can be acceptor states. There are more than $a$ subsets; how many are there? $(b+1)^a$ is only the number of possible ways to assign the transitions from a single state; there are that many possibilities for each state.

Comment: So if there are $a$ states and each state can have $(b+1)^a$  transitions. This would mean that there are $a(b+1)^a$? I'm still trying to grasp the number of acceptor states. If subset of the states can be acceptor states, does that mean there are $a!$, but this seems really large so I might be thinking about this wrong.

Comment: @user27546: Suppose that there are $2$ states. The transitions for one of them can be assigned in $(b+1)^2$ ways. So can the transitions for the other. And the way that the transitions are assigned for one state is completely independent of the way that they’re assigned for the other, so each of the $(b+1)^2$ possible assignments for one state can be combined with any of the $(b+1)^2$ possible assignments for the other state. By the multiplication principle that gives you $(b+1)^2\cdot(b+1)^2=(b+1)^4$ possible ways to assign the transitions. Now generalize that from $2$ to $a$ states.

Comment: @user27546: For the other question, how many subsets does a set of $a$ things have? It’s not $a!$.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it helps a lot. For the first one, in two states you would have $(b+1)^{2^2}$. if I generalize it to just $a$ then would it be $(b+1)^{a^a}$?

Comment: @user27546: No, you’re multiplying together $a$ copies of $(b+1)^a$, so you get $\left((b+1)^a\right)^a=(b+1)^{a^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Number of possible initial states : $a$
Number of possible final states : $2^a$
Number of possible transitions: (as shown above) : $(b+1)^(a^2)$ and for each of these transitions we have $2^a$ possible states.  So total choices : $2^(b+1)^(a^2)$

So possible number of NFAs : $a*2^a* 2^(b+1)^(a^2)$